# The category of monoid objects

Tags: category-theory, monoid, monoidal-categories

Let $C$ be a cartesian category.

We can form the category $\text{Mon}(C)$ of monoid objects in $C$. If $C$ is $\text{Set}$, this category is the category of monoids. If $C$ is $\text{Mon}$ (the category of monoids, with product the monoidal operation), then I suspect $\text{Mon}(C)$ is the category of commutative monoids.

I am thinking about properties of $C$ which give corresponding properties of $\text{Mon}(C)$. Here are some questions:

> 1. What are optimal conditions to put on $C$ to make coproducts distribute over products in $\text{Mon}(C)$?

For instance, I suspect that free monoid distributes over product of monoids, but I am not certain.

> 2. What are optimal conditions to put on $C$ to make products isomorphic to coproducts in $\text{Mon}(C)$?

I call this condition linearity. I think the category of commutative monoids has this property.

My interest in this question lies in trying to get a better feel for how taking monoid objects (or commutative monoid objects, or group objects,or  abelian group objects) changes the flavour of the category. So I would be greatly appreciative of any theorems in this regard.

Here are some similar examples:

1. Abelian group objects in $R$-alg / $S$ (monoidal category with products the monoidal operation) are $S$-modules. So we started with a category which was codistributive (and also extensive) and got a category which is linear (and in fact abelian).
2. Of course, rings are monoid objects in the monoidal linear category of abelian groups. Here we start with a monoidal linear category (but where the monoidal operation is not product this time) and get a codistributive category.
3. Group objects in the category of groups (a codistributive category, I think) are just abelian groups (linear category). This follows from the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument).
4. Abelian group objects and commutative monoid objects always form linear categories. Abelian group object categories are always enriched over $\text{Ab}$.

Comment: Coproducts cannot distribute over products in a non-trivial pointed category, since $X=0+X=(0\times 0)+X\to (0 +X)\times (0+X)=X\times X$ is the diagonal map.